# No access to c drive with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I get the error Access denied when I try to use mysqldump into any folder on the c drive but it works correctly if I dump it into another drive. It's a new PC running Windows 8 64 bit and I am the only user.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the permission and give access to the drive, but not recommend! just use Desktop or Documents folder to dump the sql.